# Does ProGuard support Java 11?

Tags: java, proguard

I was trying to use Proguard (6.1.0beta1) but got

```
(Unsupported version number [55.0] (maximum 54.0, Java 10)))
```

Are there alternatives to ProGuard which can manage with Java 11?

Comment: Just curious: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Can you compile your code for Java 10? Are you really using the features of Java 11?

Comment: Hint: try looking into release letters. Such tools typically tell you exactly which version of Java they are supporting.

Comment: And of course: asking for **tools recommendations** renders your question off topic. So better drop that part from your question.

Comment: The exception already tells you it is not supported, so why post the question?

Comment: There is question about alternatives

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java 11 have introduced changes to the bytecode and class file format:

- [JEP 181: Nest-Based Access Control](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/181)
- [JEP 309: Dynamic Class-File Constants](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/309)

Because of above it's unlikely that you will find a working code obfuscator at the moment. Hopefully ProGuard will be updated soon (see [#188 Support Java 11](https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/feature-requests/188/) planned for ProGuard 6.1).

Comment: I would suggest compiling for Java 10. +1

Comment: it seems I have to do this.

Comment: Another thing you could do is take out a support contract - https://www.guardsquare.com/en/support.  This will help them find the resources to add new features to your preferred obfuscator ... faster.  (Disclaimer: I have no connection or financial stake in GuardSquare or the ProGuard product.)

Answer (score 28):

As a follow-up for [Karol Dowbecki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53478832): [ProGuard 6.1.0 beta2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard%20beta/6.1beta/) (or newer) supports Java 10, 11 and 12. See [#188 Support Java 11](https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/feature-requests/188/)

---

Notice that you'll need to change the `libaryjars` for Java 9 or newer due to the introduction of the module system. Here's the section of my [Gradle Kotlin build script](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl):

```
if (JavaVersion.current().isJava9Compatible) {
    libraryjars(System.getProperty("java.home") + "/jmods")
} else {
    libraryjars(System.getProperty("java.home") + "/lib/rt.jar")
}
```

Comment: I'm facing problems making proguard compatible due to the module system. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55609008/meta-inf-version-duplicate-error-when-using-proguard. Where exactly do I make the appropriate changes in build.gradle file to account for this and what do I change/add "?

Comment: Looks like Java 12 support is still lacking from 6.1.0 beta 2 according to ProGuard issue #190. Linking my comment from it here: https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/feature-requests/190/?limit=25#81a0. There is no mention of Java 12 in the source code at all.