# META-INF/version duplicate error when using Proguard

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, meta-inf

Gradle : 4.10.1
Gradle Android Plugin version : 3.3.2
Proguard : 6.0.3
JDK - 1.9 
Android Studio 3.3.2
When I try to build apk release version along with Proguard. I get the following error -

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.InputReader.execute(InputReader.java:149)
    at proguard.ProGuard.readInput(ProGuard.java:255)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:96)
    ......
```

This seems to be caused due to this -

```
Warning: class [META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class] unexpectedly contains class [module-info]
Note: duplicate definition of program class [module-info]
Note: there were 20 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning: there were 21 classes in incorrectly named files.
         You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
         The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.
```

From extensive searching it looks like Proguard has a problem with META-INF/versions/9. I have multiple dependencies that contain this.

While the issue to seems to somewhat documented, no solutions prescribed seem to work. 
https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/665/
suggests filtering out those class files via -

```
-injars my_lib.jar(!META-INF/versions/**.class)
```

However when I try this it just labels more files as duplicate and incorrectly named. I also tried excluding it via gradle-

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/versions'
        exclude 'META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class'
   }
```

This also fails to resolve the problem. How do I solve this problem ?

Comment: I see the same issue with ProGuard 6.0.3, Gradle 5.1 and Java 1.8.0_202.

Comment: The best thing to do now is switch to R8 instead of Proguard.

Comment: Git any response

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is a very old question, but I was able to get this to work using this gradle configuration:

```
task obfuscate(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
    configuration files("proguard-project.txt")
    libraryjars files("build/rt.jar", "build/jce.jar")
    injars files("build/libs/desktop-${version}.jar"), filter: "!META-INF/versions/**/*.class"
    outjars files("build/libs/obfuscated.jar")
}
```

I think the issue with the injars directive you used might be the path - should be `META-INF/versions/**/*.class`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the option -ignorewarnings in proguard-project.txt 'fixed' it for me, the generated jar works fine as long as the only warnings mentioned by Proguard are related to META-INF.

Comment: This only works until other valid warnings are issued by ProGuard and then ignored. Unless you are 100% certain that everything is processed exactly as you intend it to be you then run the risk of encountering runtime errors.

Comment: This will ignore all warnings coming in future

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but I had issues with this when upgrading some other libs in an application.

I found the `<inLibsFilter>` tag at [the proguard maven plugin page](https://wvengen.github.io/proguard-maven-plugin/) which helped me get it to work. I used it like this (in my `<configuration>` tag:

```
            <inLibsFilter>!META-INF/versions/**</inLibsFilter>
```

Hopefully it can help others that may stumble upon it..

Comment: Just realized OP is using gradle and I maven, but there might be a similar configuration setting in gradle...

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the Gradle version will solve the issue as proguard version 6.2.1  has filter to prevent such cases
https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/665/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).