# Proguard obfuscation fails with tinylog

Tags: proguard, obfuscation, tinylog

I am using Proguard together with TinyLog. The following are defined in the proguard.conf file as it was stated on the [Tinylog home page](https://tinylog.org/v2/configuration/)

```
-keepnames interface org.tinylog.**
-keepnames class * implements org.tinylog.**
-keepclassmembers class * implements org.tinylog.** { <init>(...); }
```

The following error messages are from the obfuscation process:

```
[proguard] Note: there were 1 duplicate class definitions.
[proguard]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
[proguard] Warning: there were 2 classes in incorrectly named files.
[proguard]          You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
[proguard]          The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.
[proguard]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unexpectedclass)
[proguard]          If you don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,
[proguard]          you could try your luck using the '-ignorewarnings' option.
[proguard] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Does anyone know how to correct the errors ?

I am using tinylog 2.4.1

Using -ignorewarnings in proguard.conf is not an option

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal Android App example project that uses tinylog 2 for logging and ProGuard for obfuscation: [https://github.com/tinylog-org/tinylog-android-example](https://github.com/tinylog-org/tinylog-android-example/tree/v2). The latest stable version of Android build tools for Gradle (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0) does not output the posted warnings.

If you have to use an old version ProGuard or a custom ProGuardTask in your Gradle script, you can remove the module-info files as described here: [META-INF/version duplicate error when using Proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55609008/meta-inf-version-duplicate-error-when-using-proguard)